# Simplified: I have A in one cell, 2 in another cell, I want the value of A2 in cell C3

Tags: excel

The title is an extremely simplified version of my question.

I basically have a column of months and then a column of values.  The values are absolute-referenced to another sheet. The problem is, I want the absolute reference from =Sheet2!$D$3 to change to =Sheet2!$D$4 only when =month(A#)=3 and I want to be able to pull down this formula so it automatically changes from $D$3 to $D$4 $D$5 $D$6, etc every March but stays absolute on that value from April - Feb.

I have the result of =LEFT(FORMULATEXT(D4),LEN(FORMULATEXT(D4))-LEN(A4)) where D4 is just where I had the original formula and A4 is the =if(month=3,A3+1,A3) in D5

A =concatenate(D5,A4) should change =Sheet2!$D$3 to =Sheet2!$D$4 and it does.  But now I need to to be recognized as a formula.

Help please.

Comment: Some example data and/or images of what you are doing would really help here. Your descriptions just are not enough. Also, On what basis would constitute a formula change?

Comment: If the date is recognised by excel, then month() will give the month of that date and you can format to the number, short (mar) or long (march).

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I'm aware of the month() option, the problem is I want a LONG column of items to change from =Sheet2!$D$4 to =Sheet2!$D$5 every time the month = 3... so basically every March, I need to move down a row in the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned sample data would be preferred, but I think you are looking for the Indirect() formula. Go read up on that.

Comment: I tried Indirect() before I posted and it didn't change what I needed.

Comment: @bearlyanightowlpurplezebra if you had been clear with what you had tried then people could have targeted their effort on your behalf better.

Comment: @SolarMike yes, I forgot to mention about indirect(), but I clearly did mention the month().. and formatting wasn't an issue.

Comment: You absolutely need to use Indirect. You need to drop the Formulatext function as it adds the "=" to the result. Use something like Mid instead.

Also, remember that Indirect() is not a volatile function.